# How to make an HTML select field with two (independent) checkbox in pure CSS

Tags: html, css, checkbox, html-select

I need to make a select list where every item has two checkbox (or, at least, a single checkbox that can assume 3 values: 'x' 'v' or 'blank').

Right now I did with CSS using selected and adding the unicode character 2611 / 2610, but it has only two possible states, also if I add a second checkbox it will toggle with the click.

this code is my current situation:
 CSS:

```
select.control option::before {
  content: "\2610"; /*2612 è la crocetta*/
  width: 1.3em;
  text-align: center;
  display: inline-block;
}

select.control option:checked::before {
  content: "\2611";
}

select.control[multiple]{
    overflow-y:scroll;
    min-height: 40px;
    max-height: 30%
}
```

HTML:

```
<html>
<head><link rel='stylesheet' href='my.css'></link></head>
<body>
  <fieldset class='field_set'> 
    <span class='field_span'>
      <label style='vertical-align: top;'>Postazioni</label>
      <select class='control' name="Choose values" multiple='multiple'>
        <option value='v1'>P 1</option>
        <option value='v2'>P 2</option>
        <option value='v3'>P 3</option>
      </select>
    </span>
  </fieldset>
</body></html>
```

and this is the output:
Desired: [image: Desired]
Current: [image: Current]

Note: obviously I'd like to get both the first and the second selection values. And, if possible, not to show any highlighting (selections are enough)

Comment: You can not insert “checkboxes” into the options of a native select field. And just putting some characters in there that “look” like checkboxes, is not going to provide any actual checkbox _functionality_.

Comment: That's true, I thought existed some CSS "flags" that could be set just like 'checked' so If I see checked it mean'first box'. EX: if I see 'selected' it means the second, but I really have no idea about how to implement that. I could just have a "sequence" of clicks to enable those: 1 click is checked, 2 is checked and selected, three is only selected 4 resets.

Comment: Even if that was possible, the user would still have no way to _change_ their “checked” status then – or is that not a requirement, and you want to use those to _display_ an already set status only, and it doesn’t need to be changed in this place?

Comment: The user may click once and "check", twice and "check and select", three times and "only select" four times and "reset". I don't need that each element to be "sensitive" just being "reactive" is enough.

Comment: Even handling mere clicks on option elements can be problematic, not all browsers agree in this regard. IMHO this should not use select and option at all, but a custom HTML structure, that then gets formatting applied to make it look and behave similar to a native select field.

Comment: Does it have to be two checkboxes? Can you use one checkbox instead, but the first click renders `✓`, the second a `✗`, and a third click clears it? This demands javascript though.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can put a functional checkbox inside a select input without using javascript. The easiest way would probably be to style up a list of checkboxes to present it like a dropdown menu.

Simple solution may be to just use option groups and break your multiple checkboxes out into individual choices:

```css
select {
width: 50%;
}
```

```html
<form id="form1" class="example-form">
  <label>Option Groups
    <div>
      <select id="options" name="opt" placeholder="select one" required class="select-css">
      <option value="" disabled selected>Select One</option>
        <optgroup label="Giraffe">
          <option value="chk-green">Green Giraffe</option>
          <option value="chk-purple">Purple Giraffe</option>
          <option value="chk-both">Green &amp; Purple Giraffe</option>
        </optgroup>
        <optgroup label="Pangolin">
          <option value="png-orange">Orange Pangolin</option>
          <option value="png-pink">Pink Pangolin</option>
          <option value="png-both">Orange &amp; Pink Pangolin</option>
        </optgroup>
      </select>
    </div>
  </label>
</form>
```